# Different values for linux crc32 vs python binascii

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate the CRC-32 for various files in Python. I used the `binascii` module to do so. But when I compare the value output with the output of the `crc32` command, I get different values. Anybody know why this is happening?

I used the following python code to generate the crc32 value:

```
 crc32 = '%08x' % binascii.crc32(filename)
```

The result from the python code was `158091bb`. The result for the same filename from the `crc32` command was `52a88b67`.

Comment: Your question lacks some details to be able to answer it: How did you calculate & print the CRC values (show the code) and which CRC values did you get from the two methods for one of the files?

Comment: Ok added requested details.

Comment: `binascii.crc32` doesn't work on files, but on raw data. You need to read the data from the file yourself. What you are getting from the python code is just the CRC value of the *file name*.

Comment: Ok thanks for that. Is there any easier way to calculate the crc for a file in Python so that I don't have to read it myself?

Comment: I don't know enough Python to answer that. In any case, your questions are more suited for [so], so you might consider to ask there.

Comment: Alright thanks. Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run `crc32` on the file contents, not the filename. If the file is small enough to fit in memory this is trivial:

```
crc32 = '%08x' % binascii.crc32(open(filename, 'rb').read())
```

If the file is larger, you need to break it into chunks.

```
crcbin = 0
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        chunk = f.read(65536) # magic constant, use whatever you feel is appropriate
        if not chunk:
            break
        crcbin = binascii.crc32(chunk, crcbin)
crc32 = '%08x' % crcbin
```

Comment: Thanks. I have selected your answer, though in the end I decided to ditch the the python module and just use call the `crc32` command line utility instead. I decided to do this because the python module returns a signed integer as the CRC, even though the standard defines the CRC to be an unsigned long. For this reason, the Python module is useless at least 50% of the time when working with CRCs from other programs.

Comment: @KG that's easy to correct, just use `(crcbin & 0xffffffff)`. Python doesn't have unsigned types so it does the best it can.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for this. Though I don't get the logic of how this works. Won't ANDing with that value just produce the same number again?

Comment: @KG an `int` in Python is essentially unlimited in size. You're getting back a 33-bit positive signed value which is indistinguishable from a 32-bit unsigned one.